# Indexing in solr using java code?

Tags: indexing, solr, solrj

I have some code in java to index all files of a folder and its subfolders in Solr using recursive calls.Is there any quick way to index files or some direct Solr function to index all files of a folder recursively????

**public static void TraverseFiles(File[] file) {**

```
  for (File file : files) {

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                  TraverseFiles(file.listFiles(),i);

        } 
        else {
            file_path=file.getAbsolutePath();
            file_ext=FilenameUtils.getExtension(file_name);
            //a function to index file
            IndexFile(file_path,file_ext);
       }
  }
```

**}**

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want - more - code of Java? Do you want a way that's not in Java? Could you clarify where you are stuck.

Comment: Here in this example I am creating my own recursive function TraverseFiles(File[] file) to recursively find files in parent folder and its subfolders and processing each file one by one for indexing.                                                                                                    I want to use any direct solr function or method to find by itself to index all files of folder and its subfolders by just specifying name of parent folder location.

Comment: eg: some_solr_function("/user/home");

Comment: bin/post supports recursive directory navigation and indexing. Don't even need Java code for that.